# How to insert multiple records with same column in one shot?

Tags: sql

Can you help me to insert multiple records in one shot? My query works but I want the fastest way to do it. The data is in excel sheet there are a lot of records I just show 3 distinct records for the sake of sample. Here's my query...

```
INSERT INTO master_tbl (DESC,CODE) VALUES
  ('A','1'),
  ('A','2'),
  ('A','3'),
  ...
```

**DATA**
A  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
B  1 2 3 4
C  1 2

**RESULT**
DESC  CODE
A     1
A     2
A     3
A     4

---

---

- 

> List item

---

- 

```
  5
```

A     6
A     7`

> `enter code here`

`
A     8
A     9
B     1
B     2
B     3
B     4
C     1
C     2

Comment: `insert into ... values (...), (...), ...` seems like the right way to do it. What makes you think that it is not fast enough? Also, please consider properly formating your question - as it stands, it is quite unreadable.

Comment: Sorry for my format. Yeah, that's the easiest way to do it, I think I should have asked about the excel formula how to compact the multiple data in one entry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax of insert statements for your records -

```
INSERT INTO master_tbl (DESC,CODE) VALUES ('A','1');
INSERT INTO master_tbl (DESC,CODE) VALUES ('A','2');
```

This is a good way to insert records. If you have finite number of values, you can go with `INSERT..SELECT` with `Cartesian join`.

Sample SQL -

```
insert into master_tbl(desc, code)
select t1.col1, t2.col1
(select 'A' as col1 from dual
union
select 'B' from dual
union
select 'C' from dual
union 
select 'D' from dual) t1
join
(select '1' as col1 from dual
union
select '2' from dual
union
select '3' from dual
union 
select '4' from dual) t2;
```

Are you looking for a help to create 'insert' script out of excel sheet?

You can use `CONCATENATE` function in excel to place your cell values. Assuming these two columns are placed in `A` and `B` cells in excel. You can extend this function to all records in your sheet.

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO master_tbl (DESC,CODE) VALUES ('",A2,"','",B2,"');")
```

Comment: Shantanu Kher exactly what I want, let me try if it works...

Comment: Glad to hear that!!  Hope it helps

Comment: Shantanu Kher It doesn't work as there are multiple records in one row. Any idea to transpose them in one column first? Let's say A 1 then beneath A 2 then beneath A 3 so basically there are two columns left for all.

Comment: Are you asking it with reference to excel ?

Comment: Pls update your question with details. I or someone else will take a look and help.